# Json to Java Object returns null values

Tags: json, spring-boot

My Pojo class
public class User{

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private Date dob;

@java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"id", "name", "dob"})
public User(Long id, String name, Date dob) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
}

public User() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public Date getDob() {
    return this.dob;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
```

}

Request:

{"name":"Reddy","dob":"2018-02-16T04:16:29.698+0000"}

Response: I'm incrementing ID if doesn't exist
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": null,
    "dob": null
}

Comment: Post the code that performs conversion

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/create", consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public User create(User user){
       return userDaoService.save(user);
    }

Comment: 1) It's better to update the question rather posting code in comments. 2) Any exceptions in server log? Date conversion may be broken

Comment: I got the answer.... I missed @RequestBody annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gson for unmarshalling, try the below.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson() ;
 data = gson.fromJson("Your Json", User.class)
```

Comment: No I'm using JSON